# How to generate code analysis log file from MSBUILD command line

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, code-analysis

I build and code analysis my C++ project with **MSBUILD** command line like this:

```
MSBUILD %solution% /m /t:build /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=Win32 /p:RunCodeAnalysis=true /p:CodeAnalysisLogFile=D:\MyXmlReport.xml
```

But I didn't get the code analysis log file at the location I defined(**D:\MyXmlReport.xml**), only the default log file.
Anybody know how to get the code analysis log file?

Comment: I have the same problem, however I get `"MSBUILD : error MSB1006: Property is not valid."` when trying to set it on the command line. Did you ever find a solution ?

Comment: No, I just pick logs from the default location.